# Error ADMA5026E for WebSphere Application Server Network Deployment

Tags: deployment, websphere

What I'm doing wrong that I get the ADMA5026E error when deployment an application with the NetworkDeployment Console?

Comment: If you need people to assist you, provide elaborate information. Paste the error log contents. If you provide a one liner problem statements chances are references to Info center is what you will get. That is the best that people can do to help you out.

Answer (score 1):

Try

[IBM Information Center](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/wasinfo/v6r1/topic/com.ibm.websphere.messages.doc/com.ibm.ws.management.resources.AppDeploymentMessages.html?resultof=%22%41%44%4d%41%35%30%32%36%45%22%20%22%61%64%6d%61%35%30%32%36%22%20)